# specFlow error : ScenarioTearDown threw Object reference not set to an instance of an object excetion

Tags: specflow

I am facing the issue in specflow scenario testing as follows.

1.It is Throwing exception in Tear Down method as Object reference not set to an instance of the object.
2.Which is resulting in the test failure although test passes successfully.

plz help.

Following is the feature.cs file

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org/).
//      SpecFlow Version:1.9.2.1
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:1.9.0.0
//      Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18052
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#region Designer generated code
#pragma warning disable
namespace FunctionalTest.SpecFlowScenarios.APIKeyFixtures
{
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "1.9.2.1")]
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute()]
    public partial class CreateAPIKeyFeature
    {

        private static TechTalk.SpecFlow.ITestRunner testRunner;

#line 1 "CreateAPIKey.feature"
#line hidden

        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ClassInitializeAttribute()]
        public static void FeatureSetup(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext testContext)
        {
            testRunner = TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner();
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo featureInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "CreateAPIKey", "", ProgrammingLanguage.CSharp, ((string[])(null)));
            testRunner.OnFeatureStart(featureInfo);
        }

        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ClassCleanupAttribute()]
        public static void FeatureTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnFeatureEnd();
            testRunner = null;
        }

        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestInitializeAttribute()]
        public virtual void TestInitialize()
        {
            if (((TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureContext.Current != null) 
                        && (TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title != "CreateAPIKey")))
            {
                Tavisca.Vexiere.FunctionalTest.SpecFlowScenarios.APIKeyFixtures.CreateAPIKeyFeature.FeatureSetup(null);
            }
        }

 // this method is throwing the null ref exception
       [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCleanupAttribute()]
        public virtual void ScenarioTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioEnd();
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioSetup(TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo)
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioStart(scenarioInfo);
        }

        public virtual void ScenarioCleanup()
        {
            testRunner.CollectScenarioErrors();
        }

        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute()]
        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DescriptionAttribute("CreateAPIKey_Success")]
        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestPropertyAttribute("FeatureTitle", "CreateAPIKey")]
        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategoryAttribute("createAPIKey")]
        public virtual void CreateAPIKey_Success()
        {
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo("CreateAPIKey_Success", new string[] {
                        "createAPIKey"});
#line 5
this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
#line 7
testRunner.Given("that an Organization is already set up in Vexiere hierarchy.", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
#line 8
testRunner.When("I want to register new APIKey for above created organization.", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");
#line 9
testRunner.Then("It should create new APIKey as per requested.", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");
#line hidden
            this.ScenarioCleanup();
        }
    }
}
#pragma warning restore
#endregion
```

Comment: Could you just add a null check or a try/catch/ignore block to your Tear Down method?

Comment: It is not my custom code throwing exception but SecenarioTearDown method from abc.feature.cs file throwing an exception.

Comment: I see, it would be really helpful if you could add the feature file to the question, or a link to it, and/or the generated C# code that is throwing a null reference exception

Comment: @Phillip Trelford- added feature.cs file

Comment: thanks, either `testRunner` is null when it calls `testRunner.OnScenarioEnd()` or the null reference is coming from inside that call, can you provide the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as I've just run into a similar problem (I don't think it's the original posters problem) however it might be useful for other folks.

When running my specflow tests on a TFS build server using release manager my app.token.config file was slightly different from the normal app.config file. (release manager copies the app.token.config file changing things like server names over the config file during the build/release process)

In my case I had recently added a language setting to the specflow settings in app.config.

```
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
    <stepAssemblies>
      <stepAssembly assembly="SpecResults" />
    </stepAssemblies>
    <language feature="en-GB" />
  </specFlow>
```

However in the app.token.config file (which is what the tests use at runtime) the `unitTestProvider` element was missing (cut n paste typo) and some of our tests which used an `[AfterScenario]` cleanup routine gave a `NullReferenceException`. Adding the `unitTestProvider` element to the app.token.config fixed my problem.

Note the app.token.config is a release manager 2013 specific issue but it might be worth checking the .config file your tests are running with to make sure it has the unitTestProvider element.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you use the NUnit unitTestProvider, rather than xUnit (my case) or  MSTest (in OPs case); then it will work fine.

I am guessing this has to do with differences in the test life cycle (parallel running?) of the different testing frameworks.